# Google Play not reporting crashes

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm in a bad spot. I am developing an Android app for a customer. The customer tells me that the app crashes immediately when he runs it. I cannot reproduce this behavior. It runs correctly on all the devices I have available for testing.

What I need is the crash log from the customer's phone, but it doesn't show up in Google Play console. This has been happening for over a week, and the Crashes/ANRs screen is still empty.

Why isn't the crash being reported? What else can I do?

Comment: Crash reporting isn't 100%.  Have the user capture a log via logcat if they're technical enough.  If that isn't an option, try finding out their device type and see if Amazon or similar service allows rental of that device (Amazon has a pay per hour test rig where you can rent Android devices and control them remotely)

Answer (score 0):

Use try/catch around all suspected code and log errors on a file the user can send you, or use an exhaustive Snackbar/Toast message. The most likely source of grief is found while trying to load or generate the view from corrupted or missing resource files.